# MSI Patches: Can we deliver new Components/Files with patches?

Tags: wix, patch

**Simply question:** Can we deliver new files/components using Patches?

I actually tried Purely Wix method i.e. http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm, but not working for me.

Patch Creation Properties (pcp) method didn't give me any option to do so, that's why its out of my context now.

Our installers are already capable to Major Upgrade, but just in case of 2 or 3 news files, we intend to avoid giving 500+ MB build to users, instead considering giving small patches.

Above mentioned procedure seems to be working fine to deliver updates files for already installed ones.

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "not working for me"? Did you receive any errors?

Comment: I never find any option to add new files with pcp method, so its not working for me. :)

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed Patch is difference between two complete install packages, .msi files. You can try to create your patch by [following this instruction](https://alexyv.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wix-patching/). In your case you can use the source files directly.